Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS - sudo apt update does not work - lunar release no longer have a release
When I try updating in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, I get this error:
user:/home/user# sudo apt update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  InRelease [1,572 B]
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  InRelease [1,572 B]
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                   
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease         
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
.
.
.            
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                         
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 69.197.146.179 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.'''

How can I fix the issue with lunar repositories?

This question is similar to: How do I restore the default repositories? and What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 23.04 reached EOL long ago (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/) which is why there are errors with the lunar or 23.04 repository. After a release goes EOL, the main archive is moved and mirrors are free to drop support, thus errors can be expected. If you're using noble or 24.04 you should NOT have any EOL lunar repositories, so explore why it was added, as something is wrong, or was done in error.

Fix the sources defined in /etc/apt/ by commenting out anything lunar related
